# Fetch As Google displays my website not like Chrome does

Tags: google-chrome, seo, polymer, web-component, google-search-console

I have a website and in Google Chrome in looks like this:

[image]

But in When I use Fetch as Google in Google Webmaster tools, it looks like this:

[image]

My website is build with Polymer and WebComponents.
I checked the encoding, and it is utf-8.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your website is based on JavaScript for rendering of your HTML.

> The Google indexing system renders webpages using the HTML of a page
>   as well as its assets such as images, CSS, and Javascript files. To
>   see the page assets that Googlebot cannot crawl and to debug
>   directives in your robots.txt file, use the Fetch as Google and the
>   robots.txt Tester tools in Search Console

[Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en).

In order to make your website Googlebot  friendly you **should optimize your JavaScript** website for it.

This is a starting guide on the topic:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more